# If/Else statement in Styled-Components not injecting css code

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I'm designing a slide out menu drawer using React.js and Styled-Components. I want the drawer to slide out when the button is toggled and slide back in when it isn't toggled.

I was able to get it working by using a simple ternary operator when passing in the props to my styled component(see below). But it would slide out whenever my react component rendered and initialized it's state.

To fix this I tried adding an if/else statement to make sure it would only slide out on true/false instead of also sliding out on null/undefined. The problem is that now it isn't injecting the CSS properly.

---

### This code worked, but would slide out when the react component was rendered. (also the backticks aren't showing in stackoverflow for some reason, but they are there.)

```
${props => props.isToggled ? css`
  animation-name: ${slideRight};
  animation-duration: .4s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
` : css`
animation-name: ${slideLeft};
animation-duration: .4s;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
`}
```

---

This is my styled component code:

---

`````````````
const MenuDrawer = styled.div`
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 0;
height: 100vh;
background-color: #1c1c1c; 
${props => {
        if (props.isToggled === true) {
            css`
    animation-name: ${slideRight};
    animation-duration: .4s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
`
            console.log("props is equal to true and" + props.isToggled);

        } else if (props.isToggled === false) {
            css`
    animation-name: ${slideLeft};
    animation-duration: .4s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    `
            console.log("props is equal to false and" + props.isToggled);
        } else {
            console.log("nothing to see here");
        }
    }}
`;

export default MenuDrawer;

````````````
And this is my react component code.
```````````

class MenuToggle extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            toggled: null
        };
        //console.log("toggled is equal to:", this.state.toggled);
    }

    render(){
        //console.log("toggled is equal to:", this.state.toggled);
        const handleToggle = () => {
            if(!this.state.toggled)
            this.setState({
                toggled: true
            });
            if(this.state.toggled === false){
                this.setState({
                    toggled: true
                });
                //console.log("toggled is equal to:", this.state.toggled);
            }else if(this.state.toggled === true){
                this.setState({
                    toggled: false
                });
                //console.log("toggled is equal to:", this.state.toggled);
            }
        }
        return(
            <div>
            <MenuIcon onClick={handleToggle} isToggled={this.state.toggled}>
                <img src={QueenCityMenu} alt="icon" />
            </MenuIcon>

            <div>
                <MenuDrawer isToggled={this.state.toggled}>
                    <MenuItems isToggled={this.state.toggled}>
                        <MenuItem isToggled={this.state.toggled}>Home</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem isToggled={this.state.toggled}>About</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem isToggled={this.state.toggled}>Services</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem isToggled={this.state.toggled}>Contact</MenuItem>
                    </MenuItems>
                </MenuDrawer> 
            </div>

            </div>

        );
    }
}

export default MenuToggle;
`````````````

---

The ideal end result of this is to have the "slideRight" animation show when the menu is toggled. This will cause the drawer to slide out to the right. And when the menu is toggled off, the "slideLeft" animation should play. This will cause the drawer to slide back.

Ideally, the drawer should not slide out on load or any other time besides when the menu is toggled on/off.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: where does the right variable come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you only change `animation-name` use ternary operator on that. like `animation-name: ifToggle ? 'slideRight' : 'slideft'`

I don't see where you are passing `slideRight` or `slideLeft` variable, should this be `props.slideRight`?

```
const MenuDrawer = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #1c1c1c;
  animation-name: ${ths.pros => props.isToggled ?  ${slideRight} :  ${slideLeft}};
  animation-duration: .4s;
  nimation-fill-mode: forwards;
`;
```

Change your return method like this , to stop animation from playing by default.

```
return (
  <div>
    <MenuIcon onClick={handleToggle} isToggled={this.state.toggled}>
      <img src={QueenCityMenu} alt="icon" />
    </MenuIcon>

    <div>
      { this.state.toggled !== null &&
        <MenuDrawer isToggled={this.state.toggled}>

        <MenuItems isToggled={this.state.toggled}>
          <MenuItem isToggled={this.state.toggled}>Home</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem isToggled={this.state.toggled}>About</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem isToggled={this.state.toggled}>Services</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem isToggled={this.state.toggled}>Contact</MenuItem>
        </MenuItems>
      </MenuDrawer>
      }
    </div>

  </div>

);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! This helped me simplify my code down a lot. The functionality works, but it's still playing the animation on page load/when my react component is first rendered. 

Any ideas how to get around that?